# C++ Struct on Class

Tags: c++

need some guide here

I got a code which is

```
struct Point
{
   int x;
   int y;
};
```

then at my class i got a function

```
class MyClass
{
   private:
      Point myPoint[4];
   public:
     void setPoint();
};

void MyClass::setPoint()
{
   int xData,yData;

   for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
      cout << "Please enter x-ordinate:";
      cin >> xData;

      cout << "Please enter y-ordinate:";
      cin >> yData;

      //at this part the code throw a segmentation core dump.
      myPoint[i].x = xData;
      myPoint[i].y = yData;
   }

}
```

On first run nothing happen, but on 2nd loop, segmentation core dump occur. whats wrong with my code?

Additional code on main.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"

int main()
{
MyClass *mClass;

mclass->setPoint();
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What does "run" mean to you? Execute `setPoint`? Create a `MyClass`?

Comment: compile the code and execute, then i run the setPoint function at main class which then i key in the value, and on 2nd prompting of x-ordinate , got thrown a segmentation core dump error.

Comment: you probably never initialized your structs?

Comment: Don't know if this will fix your problem, but you might want to validate that you were able to convert the user input successfully. `do { cout << "Please enter x-ordinate: "; cout.flush(); } while( cin >> xData );` And please post the code where you create an instance of `MyClass` and call `setPoint`

Comment: you should show us you 'main' function or whereever you create your instance of MyClass and call setPoint.

Comment: @AK4749 , what do you mean by Initialize my struct?

Comment: i'm just wondering if you created MyClass properly

Comment: I'm hesitant to look beyond the unchecked input operations. Fix the input logic first; then we can see about the rest.

Comment: The code that you have shown us is not the culprit. If your program is failing, it is because of **some other part** of your code. Please reduce your original program to the shortest complete program that demonstrates the error and copy-paste that into the question. See http://sscce.org for more details.

Comment: it start fail at       myPoint[i].x = xData;

Comment: @user1777711 that doesn't mean it's the culprit. That could be the location of the error caused by a coding error in a different location. I'd take Rob's advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must allocate memory before use pointer:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass *mClass = new MyClass ();
    mclass->setPoint();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, it's a good practice to use the destructor when allocating new objects with `new`.

Comment: Why new? `MyClass mClass; mclass.setPoint();`

Comment: I guess he want to use pointer so why not?

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass *mClass;

mclass->setPoint();
```

There's your problem right there. You have never allocated an object, just a pointer.

```
int main () 
{
  MyClass mclass;
  mclass.setPoint();
}
```

As an alternative, if you require an object whose lifetime extends beyond the scope of your variable, you could allocate the object with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in creating the object. More precisely in your code you have not created a object.Its merely a pointer for which there is memory allocation happened.It should be like this:

```
MyClass *mClass = new MyClass();
mClass->setPoint();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need memory allocation for your object

```
MyClass *obj = new MyClass();
                ^
```

**new** is a language construct that dynamically allocates memory

Answer (score 0):

related to the construction of an object.

```
MyClass *mClass;
```

means you get a Myclass pointer, this pointer has ability to deal with a Myclass-type object, just has ability. but you haven't got an "real object", "real object" means you apply and get a block of memory on the system heap.
then

```
mclass->setPoint();
```

this call means call the function of a Myclass-type **object** instead of call the function of a **Myclass-class**.

So, the code may be correct is:

```
MyClass *mClass = new MyClass ();
mclass->setPoint();
```

the new keyword means apply a block of memory for a Myclass-type object.